# Refresh token rotation and password loss

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, refresh-token

In my web application I am using access and refresh tokens to authorize user access to protected resources, the flow is as following:

1. The user, through a mobile app, sends a request to the "auth/token" endpoint providing his credentials. The server authenticates the user and issue an access and refresh token. The refresh token is saved in a whitelist to be able to revoke it later on, if necessary.
2. Upon access token expiration, the mobile app sends the refresh token to the "/token/refresh" endpoint presenting the refresh token. A new access/refresh token pair is created and the old refresh token is invalidated ,implementing in this way the token rotation.

Now the problem:
Let's say that the client refresh the token but never receive a response back from the server because the network is lost. After 30 mins the client tries to refresh again but its token is now invalid and the user is logged out. In the Oauth implementations we can set a time for the old token after which this will be invalidated, giving the possibility to the mobile app to resend the same refresh token if any problem occurs. But I do not think this is a solution because we can't be sure of when the mobile client will retry to refresh the token. It can be in some minutes, hours or worse also days.
How do you approach this problem?

Answer (score -1):

The first solution I could think of is increasing expiration time.